# Create shortcode to display specific post in relationship current date

Tags: shortcode

Hello i have create this script to see a saint on each different day and in relationship current day.

I use on header of template and work good:

```
           <?php  
            //Date parameter
            $currentDay = date('j');
            $currentMonth = date('n');
            //wp query to show saints name 
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","mydb","mypassword","myuser");
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }
            $sql = "select * from santi where numero_giorno= ".$currentDay." and numero_mese= ".$currentMonth;
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            if (mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        ?>
        <span id="txtSaintName"><?php echo  $row['nome']?></span>
        <?php
                }
                mysqli_close($con);
            }
        ?>
```

Now i need to trasform this in shortcode to use in a widget.

I try to do this but if i copy shortcode on page or widget and try to see i se only the number of current day and not the text. Where wrong?

```
<?php 

add_shortcode("separatore", "separatore_html_render");  

function separatore_html_render( $atts ) {  
return                <?php  
                //Date parameter
                $currentDay = date('j');
                $currentMonth = date('n');
                //wp query to show saints name 
                $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","mydb","mypassword","myuser");
                if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                }
                $sql = "select * from santi where numero_giorno= ".$currentDay." and numero_mese= ".$currentMonth;
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                if (mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0) {
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            ?>
            <span id="txtSaintName"><?php echo  $row['nome']?></span>
            <?php
                    }
                    mysqli_close($con);
                }
            ?>;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this use your desired name for function names :

```
function main_func_name() {

    //Date parameter
    $currentDay = date('j');
    $currentMonth = date('n');
    //wp query to show saints name 
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "mydb", "mypassword", "myuser");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $sql = "select * from santi where numero_giorno= " . $currentDay . " and numero_mese= " . $currentMonth;
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($con) > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            ?>
                         <span id="txtSaintName"><?php echo $row['nome'] ?></span>
            <?php
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
}

add_shortcode('shortcode_name', 'function_shortcode');

function function_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    main_func_name();
    return ob_get_clean();
}
?>
```

Comment: Yeah! This work. I have only a problem with special characthers.

I try to use     

`$sql = "select * from frasi_padre_pio where numero_giorno= " . $currentDay . " and numero_mese= " . $currentMonth;
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql, "utf8");`

But give me error :(

Comment: can you show me the error plz?

Comment: Hello i have this error 
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-content/themes/NewTheme/functions.php on line 379

Comment: query should be like : `$sql = "SELECT * FROM santi WHERE numero_giorno = " . $currentDay . " AND numero_mese = " . $currentMonth . "; & i cannot see your **line 379** in functions.php

Comment: Yes but the problem is that i can't display special character. I need insert the character (utf8) to display text correctly